# How do you close Navigation Drawer in Kivy upon another activity?

Tags: kivy, navigation-drawer

I'm using a navigation drawer in kivy but do not know where to begin in closing it upon another activity (on_release) such as clicking a button for another screen.  The drawer only closes if you click on the screen or swipe left to close it even when it leaves the current screen and go back to it. I would greatly appreciate any help or guidance.  Here is a snippet of my code:

```
NavigationDrawer:
    id: nav2
    anim_type: 'slide_above_simple'
    side_panel_width: .7*self.width
    BoxLayout:
        id: sidenav2
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: mtx.dp(10)
        spacing: 2
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: rgba('#E1E1E0')
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size   
         BlinkButton:
             text: icon('zmdi-comment-list')
             font_size: mtx.sp(20)
             color: rgba('#ffffff') if self.state == 'normal' else rgba('#0ADB0D')
             markup: True
             size_hint_x: .10
             on_release: 
                 nav2.toggle_state()
             canvas.before:
                 Color:
                    rgba: rgba('#030B35')
                 Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
             FlatButton:
                    text: 'Next Screen'
                    color: rgba('#000000')
                    font_size: mtx.sp(14)
                    on_release: 
                        scrn_mngr.current = 'next_screen '
                        scrn_mngr.transition.direction = 'left'
                    height: 70
                    canvas.before:
                        Color:
                            rgba: rgba('#ffffff')
                        RoundedRectangle:
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size
                            radius: [0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the toggle_state to set_state()

Comment: I am assuming this is where you are referring to `on_release: nav2.toggle_state()`. When you provide answers, please be more specific and explain what you want the OP to do.

Comment: I intentionally gave the answer that way. Because when I checked the whole code, there was only one occurrence of the part I referred to so I thought he would be able to grab it.  Anyway, thanks for the heads up, I will be more specific next time.